# jssor with dynamic $Align

Tags: jquery, css, slider, jssor

Is it somehow possible to change the $Align runtime?

I have a content-container (lets say width: 1000px) with margin-left and -right set to auto. So the container is centered. The container for the slider has 100% and the slides have width set to 1000px. What I want now is that the active slide is allways in the middle (like the content-container) and the other slides are left and right of it. So the only idea I have is to reset the $Align on runtime everytime window gets a resize.

Is this somehow possible?

my current options:

```
var initialmargin = parseInt($("#page").css("margin-left"));

         var options = {
                $AutoPlay: false,

                $PauseOnHover: 1,                               //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slideshow is auto playing, default value is false

                $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                          //Allows arrow key to navigate or not
                $SlideWidth: 870,                                   //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, the default is width of 'slides' container
                $SlideHeight: 300,                                  //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, the default is width of 'slides' container
                $SlideSpacing: 30,                                  //Space between each slide in pixels
                $Cols: 2,                                  //Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1
                $Align: initialmargin,                                //The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled).

                $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {                       //[Optional] Options to specify and enable arrow navigator or not
                    $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                    $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                    //$AutoCenter: 2,                                 //[Optional] Auto center arrows in parent container, 0 No, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
                    $Steps: 1                                       //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
                }
            };
```

As you can see I use the margin-left of the #page to init $Align. Now I would like to change this value something like:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  initialmargin = parseInt($("#page").css("margin-left"));
  //set initialmargin as new $Align
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to set $Align dynamically.
You can place your slider in a wrapper to make it auto center.

```
<div style="position: relative; width: 100%; background-color: #003399; overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="position: relative; left: 50%; width: 5000px; text-align: center; margin-left: -2500px;">
        <div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; margin: 0 auto;...">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Reference: http://www.jssor.com/testcase/auto-center-slider-with-no-scale.source.html

Comment: I can think of a work around where I create the slider much bigger and then set the slider left depending on window size, so that it fits the margin-left of the other content. While the container itself got 100% width and overflow hidden. But for now it looks like the customer is happy how it is right now. Anyway consider if you don't wanna add the posibility to change initial-options and update the slider with the new options. I like your slider and that would really improve it!

Comment: Changing $ParkingPosition dynamically is resonable, I will add more API later.